# How do I connect Google+ with Twitter?

Tags: twitter, google-plus

I want my Google+ account to be automatically updated when I post a tweet on Twitter.

Comment: Try this: http://joshkerr.com/post-your-tweets-to-your-google-plus/

Answer (score 9):

Google+ API is not yet public, so there's no way to auto-update your Twitter posts to G+.

You *can*, however, do the other way around: [post to Google+ and have it auto-update](http://gplus.sagg.im/) to Twitter. And Facebook too.

Comment: It can be done. Have a look at http://twoogleplus.com/. Its an online service that automatically cross-posts tweets to Google+. No browser extension needed.

Comment: It is now.... https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: @Rondo the api is still read only.

Comment: So it is. My apologies and thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible (currently) to update Twitter from G+ without a browser extension. You should wait for the API.

The best way to update Twitter and Facebook from G+ that I have come across is to get your public RSS feed for your Google+ profile and then use a service like Twitterfeed to update Facebook and Twitter or use Manage Flitter.
More detailed info here:
http://iag.me/socialmedia/tools/how-to-update-twitter-and-facebook-with-your-google-posts/

You can even decide which posts you want to sync to Facebook and/or Twitter using tags (eg #fb or #tw)