# Feed my Google+ account from Twitter

Tags: facebook, google, twitter, google-plus, twitter-integration

Looking for a way to have Google+ automatically add my tweets to my Google+ timeline.

Currently, I'm setup so that:

Google Reader, Pandora Likes, Ping Likes feed into -> Twitter

And Twitter feeds into -> Facebook

So If I have something to say, I can plaster it on twitter, and it gets CC'd to my Facebook Status as well.

Looking for some way to do the same thing with Google+  ... Ideally I only want to put statuses into one social network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect Google+ with Twitter?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17309/how-do-i-connect-google-with-twitter)