# How do I make my Twitter posts auto-post to Google+?

Tags: twitter, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect Google+ with Twitter?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17309/how-do-i-connect-google-with-twitter)

Every time I search Google for this, I find people telling me how I can post **from** G+ to Twitter and Facebook.  I want the opposite: to post from Twitter to G+.  Does anyone know of an app that does this in the background, so I can post to Twitter from my phone or desktop client and have it go to G+?