# How to update Google+ status via Twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect Google+ with Twitter?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17309/how-do-i-connect-google-with-twitter)

How do I setup my Google+ status to update from Twitter?

On the web there seems to be information on connecting social networks and cross-post on several. For instance:

- [How to Update Your Twitter Status Via Google+](http://www.avitricks.info/2011/07/how-to-update-your-twitter-status-via-google.html)
- [How to update Facebook via Google+](http://justinbee.tumblr.com/post/7314683189/how-to-update-facebook-from-google-without-using-an)
- [How to update Facebook via Twitter](http://mashable.com/2009/05/25/twitter-to-facebook/#view_as_one_page-gallery_box1809)

What about how to update Google+ via Twitter? Anybody who has set this up easily?

Comment: This question is incorrectly closed as a duplicate: The other question is about how to find contacts, which also appear on G+. This question is about how to update your own G+ status via Twitter status messages. I think there is a big difference. And hence this question is unanswered

Comment: Does http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17309/how-do-i-connect-google-with-twitter address your question?

Comment: thanks @phwd, it addresses my question, but has no relevant answer (as of 2011-10-24). I will keep this question open a while to see if some answers come up.

Comment: Unfortunately, if it adresses your question then I will have to close this question as a duplicate of the one mentioned. If you would like to raise awareness, you can attach a bounty to that question. Sorry about that, it's best to keep all answers in one post. I wouldn't attach a bounty now if I were you though, Google + API only has write access currently, so there will be no solutions until that is addressed.

Comment: Perfectly OK, no need for you to feel sorry about it :)