# Forward tweets automatically to Google+

Tags: twitter, google-plus, rss, if-this-then-that

is there a way to automatically forward tweets to Google+?

This IFTTT recipe seemed to work for a while. Well in Germany it does not work :) I tried it by myself. It's not possible for me to receive this hidden email adress. The SMS server is not answering.

https://ifttt.com/recipes/85782

Comment: Google+ doesn't have an API for writing to your stream. I guess that Google has plugged that particular security hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [How do I connect Google + with Twitter?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17309/how-do-i-connect-google-with-twitter) the lack of full read/write API for Google+ means that you can't directly tweet to G+ as of yet. However, there are browser extensions and third-party services that allow you to cross-post. 
[Google+Tweet](http://crossrider.com/install/529-google+tweet) allows you to integrate Twitter into your Google Plus account. Certain applications, such as [HootSuite](https://hootsuite.com/) have been given enough access to the API to be able to cross-post.

Comment: Well sad, but true :) Thank you for the tips of Google+Tweet and HootSuite. I guess i will use HootSuite in the future.